# Apply css to divs inside the DataList in asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, datalist

I am confused if we can apply css to divs that are inside the DataList.I have a stylesheet and a aspx page that is inheriting a master page.The master page has a contentplaceholder.And the content placeholder is where i have defined my DataList.Now i have many divs inside the datalist that needs styling.How do i give them style form stylesheet **NOT** from the aspx page itself like `<div style=" height:200px " >`.It works but i need to define the css in the stylesheet not in the aspx.

Here my datalist

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ccont" Runat="Server">
  <div id="ccont">
      <asp:DataList ID="mydatalist" ItemStyle-CssClass="lft_c_down"  runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="lft_c">
                <div id="lft_c_top">
                   <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ipath")%>' Height="250px" Width="300px" />
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div class="lft_c_down">
                   <b>Product Name:</b>
                   <asp:Label ID="lbl2" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"products") %>' runat="server" />
                   <br/>
                   <b>brand:</b>
                   <asp:Label ID="lbl1" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"brand") %>' runat="server" />
                   <br/>
                   <b>Price:</b>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"price") %>' runat="server" />
                </div>
           </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:DataList>

  </div>
```

As you can see i have a div at the starting of the contentplaceholder whose id is ccont and i can apply css there from stylesheet.**Its not working for the divs inside the datalist.**

**EDIT**
Here's my css

```
#lft_c_down
 {
   background-color:Aqua;
   color:Red;      
  }
```

Comment: Could you please post some of the CSS?

Comment: What version of .net is this?

Comment: The dotnet version i am using is 4.5

Answer (score 0):

DataList's Default rendered html is Table. That is why your css is not working. If you dont want table style, Try Repeater this css will work.

Comment: SO its not possible to call div class/id from external stylesheet for those divs inside datalist?But then why would it work if i am to place css in the same page inside style tag ie `<style lft_c_down{ height:30px }>` Or directly insert style inside div as `<div style="  ">`.

Comment: @user35 because, it will be css inheritance. Your other style will cause that change. So you try  to inspect html & style in firbug & fix it. Try to use repeater. You can control all style from stylesheet. No interference.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

Place a ContentPlaceHolder in the Head section of your Masterpage like this;

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ccont" runat="server">        
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, in the Webform, put the link to the external CSS file in head sections placeholder like this;

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link href="24857957.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ccont" runat="server">
        <div id="ccont">
      <asp:DataList ID="mydatalist" ItemStyle-CssClass="lft_c_down"  runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="lft_c">
                <div id="lft_c_top">
                   <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='http://placehold.it/140x140' Height="140px" Width="140px" />
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div class="lft_c_down">
                   <b>Product Name:</b>
                   <asp:Label ID="lbl2" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"product") %>' runat="server" />
                   <br/>
                   <b>brand:</b>
                   <asp:Label ID="lbl1" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"brand") %>' runat="server" />
                   <br/>
                   <b>Price:</b>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"price") %>' runat="server" />
                </div>
           </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:DataList>
  </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Sorry for that i was actually trying with every possible way.I had'nt had that defined inside Datalist.It was just an experiment.Removing it wouldnt work as well.And as for using inline style it works but the thing is i want it outside the aspx page.

Comment: Ah ok. Yes I understand that you want the CSS outside of the page, I've just put in the HEAD for illustrative purposes but I have it working with an external style sheet.

Comment: Yet another information...i have no head section in this page since it is inheriting the masterpage.It has only a content placeholder.Yes i can place link inside the contentplaceholder or i can include the link in the master page but both are not working.